# Fist time install on fresh machine with bios f.33

Tags: boot, startup

I have installed Ubuntu on my hp 250 g7 notebook it previously comes with win10 but i switched to Ubuntu now every time i start my pc i have to repeat whole process of booting via GNU grub ver 2.04. What should I do for login directly from my hard disc if the dvd is not inserted it shows install os on hard disc

Comment: I don't think you actually installed the OS and you are still booting from the DVD...

Comment: Ya that's the main problem os is still on dvd after completing installation as soon as i restart it there is no os in hard disc